# x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (2700,) and (200,)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a NumPy array (2,4) and I want to rotate it 90 degrees to the left and I use `np.rot90`

For example, if my array is

```
x = [[5,6,7,8],
     [1,2,3,4]]
```

and when I rotate, it will be

```
y = [[8,4],
     [7,3],
     [6,2],
     [5,1]]
```

`x` is (2,4) NumPy array and `y` will be (4,2)

```
y = np.rot90(x)
```

But when I run this code I get this failure

```
x and y must have the same first dimension, but have shapes (4,) and (2,)
```

Comment: Which line of the code is given the error message? If you remove `y=` in front of the assignment, and just execute `np.rot90(x)` what is the error message then?

Comment: I tried your code and it returns `y` rotated  as excepted

Comment: Actuallt this isn't my real array. My array contains numbers like 3.276800000e+04. Probably I get this failure because of this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your current example does not seem to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Not that computionally beautiful but working:

```
import numpy as np

x = [[5,6,7,8],

     [1,2,3,4]]

​

y = np.zeros((len(x[0]),len(x)), dtype = int)

​

for i,j,k in zip(x[0], x[1], range (0,len(x[0]))):

    y[len(x[0])-1-k] = [i,j]

    np.asmatrix(y)

print (y)

[[8 4],
 [7 3],
 [6 2],
 [5 1]]
```